# JavaScript教えてください２

Tags: javascript, vscode

JavaScriptでの`=`や`console.log`の色が赤や青になることがシンタックスハイライトというのは、わかりました。

先ほどの質問の続きになりますが、シンタックスハイライトが反映されなくても通常ならコードが読み込めるということで間違いないでしょうか。そうであるならば、このようにエラーになってJavaScriptが読み込めないのはなぜでしょうか。

下記のようにエラーコードがでます。

```
リソースを読み込むために取り込まれた: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.css:1 リソースを読み込めませんでした: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
インデックス%E3%81%B1%E3%81%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A.html:1 ORIGIN 'null'から'file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/js.tab/site.webmanifest'の内部リソースへのアクセスがCORSポリシーによってブロックされました: クロスオリジン要求はプロトコルスキームでのみサポートされています: http、データ、クロム拡張、エッジ、https、クロム信頼なし。
```

[image]

申し訳ございませんがおわかりいただける方は教えてください。

Comment: タイトルは質問の具体的な内容を示すものになるよう [edit] していただけませんでしょうか？　このタイトルだと何を解決したいのか分からず、回答を知っている人も質問一覧を見るだけでは気付くことができず、回答が集まりにくくなってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

> main.css:1 リソースを読み込めませんでした

main.cssの1行目でエラーが発生しているようです。
確かめてみて下さい。